# If they mess with my daughter, my doctor will axiom

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

My maxim is: "I'd call devil medic amid clinic six if odd minx in illicit Miami maid film hid ill will via my idyllic child, Lily."

Where am I living right now?

Hint:

> If you think it's Miami, you'll just be more confused

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps you live in

> Rome

since

> those words have a lot of Roman numerals in them -- at least half the letters in each case.

Perhaps

> the specific numbers formed by individual words are relevant, but probably not since (1) e.g. MIMI from MIAMI isn't an actually valid Roman number, and (2) the restriction to English words is probably too constraining to make it possible to make the numbers say something meaningful too.

Comment: Well done, nicely noticed ;) Specifically, only one non-conformant letter is present in any given word.

Comment: I still don't get it.

Comment: This reminds me of the old "proof" that Barney the Dinosaur is actually the devil: rot13(Gnxr gur cuenfr "PHGR CHECYR QVABFNHE", rkgenpg nyy gur Ebzna ahzrenyf (erzrzorevat gung H'f va Ebzr ybbx yvxr I'f), naq gurl nqq hc gb gur ahzore bs gur ornfg...)

Comment: @NumLock Basically, rot13(Rnpu jbeq va gur fragrapr "Zl znkvz vf: "V'q pnyy qrivy zrqvp nzvq pyvavp fvk vs bqq zvak va vyyvpvg Zvnzv znvq svyz uvq vyy jvyy ivn zl vqlyyvp puvyq, Yvyl."" svgf bar pevgrevn. Gur pevgrevn vf jurgure gur jbeq unf Ebzna ahzrenyf va vg, jvgu hc gb 1 rkprcgvba. Gur yrggref VIKYPQZ ner hfrq gb rapbqr Ebzna ahzrenyf. Fb, nf lbh pna frr, rnpu jbeq va gur fragrapr svgf gur pevgrevn nf fb: VQ PnYY QrIVY ZrQVP nZVQ PYVaVP fVK Vs bQQ ZVaK Va VYYVPVg ZVnZV ZnVQ sVYZ uVQ VYY jVYY IVn Zl VQlYYVP PuVYQ, YVYl.) (rot13 is a 13-shift Caesar cipher, for those unfamiliar  with it)

Comment: @Avi Yes, I got that part. It's the accepted answer I am commenting on after all. But how does that relate to living in Rome? One might as well conclude I live in Rome because I use the Latin alphabet right now. (And why comment in rot13?)

Comment: @NumLock Comments in rot13 as not to spoil anybody reading the puzzle and browsing the comments for the first time. In any case it's a tenuous connection, but there's not really much else to be parsed out from such a nonsensical sentence. The thought process is intended to be "What's strange about this sentence?" which then directly leads to the answer. rot13(Ng orfg gur uvag whfg pbasvezf gur nafjre, jvgu "zber" va pbashfvba (nantenzzrq) orvat "ebzr")